# I can not use Mpdf, just starting the code and some problem appear

Tags: php, mpdf

I am starting to use a library (Mpdf) to make PDF after the user fill a form (make a invoice). Is the first time, so i have been trying to fix this problem litteraly the whole day, and i give up.

The point is, when I add the require the php runs normally, but when I add the `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf ([])` it fails. And in the browser, I get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Temporary files directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp" is not writable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/ServiceFactory.php(59): Mpdf\Cache->__construct('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1033):
>
> Mpdf\ServiceFactory->getServices(Object(Mpdf\Mpdf), Object(Psr\Log\NullLogger), Array, 0, Object(Mpdf\Language\LanguageToFont), Object(Mpdf\Language\ScriptToLanguage), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/novillo.php(7): Mpdf\Mpdf->__construct(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php on line 17

I really dont have any idea of how can I fix it. I am trying to use mpdf to make a pdf

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf ([]);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Temporary files directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp" is not writable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/ServiceFactory.php(59): Mpdf\Cache->__construct('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1033): Mpdf\ServiceFactory->getServices(Object(Mpdf\Mpdf), Object(Psr\Log\NullLogger), Array, 0, Object(Mpdf\Language\LanguageToFont), Object(Mpdf\Language\ScriptToLanguage), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/novillo.php(7): Mpdf\Mpdf->__construct(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/invoice/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php on line 17

Comment: Set a custom temporary directory over which you have control. :

https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/folders-for-temporary-files.html

Comment: I tried that one but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You need a folder for temps files and you must indicate the route on constructor:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => '../../../temp']);
```

Make sure that the folder has permission to write and read, and add it in the header of the php document also indicate:

```
use \Mpdf\Mpdf;
```